# Azure key vault certificate renewal on web apps with hostname bindings

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

We are trying to set up an automatic way to update our custom certificates bound to a lot of different hostnames (custom domains) that we use on all of our web apps.

When a renewal is needed we update a new version of the certificate in our key vault on which it will automatic sync with all of the web apps that uses the certificate. This proces works fine in Azure but we still have to update the TLS/SSL bindings in the web app by hand as this will still be bound to the old certificate, even though the new certificate is synced to the web app.

Is there a workaround for this so we don't have to open every web app and change the TLS/SSL binding by hand for each hostname with the renewed certificate?

Comment: Automate the process of creating and maintaining your Azure resources with ARM templates, the Azure CLI, Azure PowerShell, Terraform, or any of the other numerous tools available. Doing things via the UI doesn't scale and isn't sustainable in the long-term for any organization.

Comment: @DanielMann currently we are doing this with pipelines (octopus and DevOps) and  ARM-templates with 200 web apps or more. But what is the point of syncing certificates with the Azure Key-Vault if TLS/SSL bindings still have to be done by hand, pipeline or ARM-template. The problem in that case is that you still have to change this certificate in all these templates and pipelines which can be really time consuming if the certificate is used in a lot of web apps.